# How to run python code in hostgator every 30 minutes?

Tags: python, linux, web-hosting

I have hostgator shared plan.
Need to put a python file in the web-host and make it run every 30 minutes.

It is a long script, but please use a simple code instead to explain for example:
a=1
a=a+1

Comment: If you have shell access, look at `cron`. Not really a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [cron](https://www.ostechnix.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cron-jobs/). You need to edit your crontab file using:

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following:

```
*/30 * * * * python script.py
```

Comment: how to write the command to run the python file for cron?  it is a linux system.

Comment: `crontab -e` like I say in the post.